# Truncate a table in SQL Server with constraint, the DBCC CheckIdent alternative is too slow, and now constraint conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I want to truncate this table I get error

```
truncate table  Mfr.datasources
```

Error:

> Cannot truncate table 'Mfr.datasources' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

I have had luck with using code such as this in the past

```
DELETE FROM [MFR].[datasources]
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[MFR].[datasources]', RESEED, 0)
```

However this table did not like that at all and after 4 minutes it displayed this error.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_FundPosition_DataSources". The conflict occurred in database "BreakManagement", table "MFR.FundPositions", column 'SourceID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Checking identity information: current identity value '12419'.

This will be part of an SSIS package in which truncating tables from DEV and then hydrating them from PROD.

Should I drop the constraints and then add them back? Would that be the best approach? What would that look like?

Comment: Um... I wouldn't drop the constraint, I'd delete the corresponding records in the other table as well if I'm deleting the records that are referenced by them...

Comment: Since you don't need to maintain the relationship if you are deleting all the data anyway, why don't you drop the constraints and re-create them after the truncate (or after the load is complete)? Why are you removing the data from this table but not the table that points at it? Maybe you should just delete the data from the other table first? Or think harder about the overall goal?

Comment: I want to truncate data from DEV , and then pump in data from PROD  @AaronBertrand

Comment: Dev or production doesn't really matter. It's about order of operations. Do you think it makes sense to delete the orders before the order details, or vice versa? I think it should be (1) truncate child (order details) (2) truncate parent (orders) (3) populate parent (4) populate child. You can do (2) before (1) *if* you drop the constraint, and similarly (4) before (3), but this is the only logical order if you don't want to drop the constraints.

Comment: You could also consider taking a backup from production (you are taking backups anyway, right?) and restoring that in production. Much, much easier than deleting all the data and replacing it.